# How to bring command to foreground with bash script

Tags: bash

At work, I login to a VPN connection.  This VPN does a 2fa connection that text me a code.  When I put the commands on a bash script, I don't get prompted for the code.  The script just sits there and eventually times out.  How can I bring the command to the foreground enter the code, then continue with the execution of the script?

```
#!/bin/bash
 
/usr/local/bin/openfortivpn -c /usr/local/Cellar/openfortivpn/my-config
#at this point it is supposed to ask me for the password and it doesn’t.  It just sits there

#rest of script#
```

Comment: Did you try already with `fg` ? What did you try already?

Comment: I attempted to use the fg,bg commands, but I guess I dont have the right syntax when running them in a bash script.  That is why I am posting here for some suggestions.

Comment: How do you invoke the script in this instance? How do you usually login to the VPN? How are you usually prompted for the PIN?